# Plotting a point with PyVista

Tags: z-index, mesh, pyvista

I want to plot a mesh in PyVista, and a point representing its center of gravity. I want the point to be always visible, even if it is behind the mesh. How can I achieve this ?

I tried finding parameters for the add_mesh function, which would change the z position of the point in order to put it on top of the mesh, but i couldn't find anything.